# Laravel HMVC routing to controller

Tags: php, laravel, hmvc

I am trying to implement CodeIgniter style folder structure to use HMVC in Laravel. I am following [this](http://blog.chenchatech.com/?p=76) tutorial. However I am unable to route to the controller inside of the modules folder. My current Laravel folder structure is:

- App
- modules

  - model
  - view
  - controller

    - UsersController.php

I want to route to some function of `UsersController`.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? And did you make sure you update your `composer.json` file to also include your `modules` folder? You also need to run `composer dump-autoload` to update the class loader. The examples that you referred to put `modules` under the `app` folder => `app/modules` (unless you deliberately choose the current structure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use route as you do with normal controllers inside of default controller folder

```
Route::any('name', array('name' => 'SomeController@someMethod'));
```

but name of two controller shouldn't be same i.e controllers on controller folder and controller inside your module folder must have different name. For same name you can use namespace.